# Is it possible to remove a boat with a villager in it without damaging the villager?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I try to destroy the boat the villager takes damage.

Comment: Make sure that you are actually aiming at the boat.  The villager won’t take damage if the boat is destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just hit the boat. It helps to turn hitboxes on by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. And of course don't use a sword.

Comment: I know what the problem was... I was destroying the boat in a three block high room, and the villagers were taking clip damage from getting stuck in the ceiling. Thanks!